# Sorting a pandas dataframe based on number of values of a categorical column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The sample dataset looks like this

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | as |
| A | 2 | sd |
| B | 3 | df |
| C | 5 | fg |
| D | 6 | gh |
| A | 1 | hj |
| B | 3 | jk |
| B | 4 | kt |
| A | 1 | re |
| C | 5 | we |
| D | 6 | qw |
| D | 7 | aa |

I want to sort the column col1 based on the number of occurences each item has, e.g. A has 4 occurences, B and D have 3 and C has 2 occurences. The dataframe should be sorted like A,A,A,A,B,B,B,D,D,D,C,C so that

Is there a way to achieve the same? Can I use sort_values to get desired result?

Comment: Yes, sort values should work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create helper column by [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and use it for sorting with `col1` by [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
df['new'] = df['col1'].map(df['col1'].value_counts())
#alternative
#df['new'] = df.groupby('col1')['col1'].transform('count')

df1 = df.sort_values(['new','col1'], ascending=[False, True]).drop('new', axis=1)
```

One line solution:

```
df1 = (df.assign(new =df['col1'].map(df['col1'].value_counts()))
         .sort_values(['new','col1'], ascending=[False, True])
         .drop('new', axis=1))

print (df1)
   col1  col2 col3
0     A     1   as
1     A     2   sd
5     A     1   hj
8     A     1   re
2     B     3   df
6     B     3   jk
7     B     4   kt
4     D     6   gh
10    D     6   qw
11    D     7   aa
3     C     5   fg
9     C     5   we
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sort_values`, but you have to provide a callable to the [`key`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html). From documentation:

> Apply the key function to the values before sorting. This is similar
> to the key argument in the builtin sorted() function, with the notable
> difference that this key function should be vectorized. It should
> expect a Series and return a Series with the same shape as the input.
> It will be applied to each column in by independently.

In your case, the key function has to count the number of times each value appears in `col1`.

```py
df.sort_values(by='col1', key=lambda x: [((df.col1 == y).sum(), -ord(y)) for y in x], ascending=False)
```

The tuple `((df.col1 == y).sum(), -ord(y))` is used to sort letters that have the same number of occurrences, using the integer representing their Unicode character.

If your dataframe is large, you should precompute these values, using `values_counts` and `map`:

```py
df.sort_values(by='col1', key=lambda x: df.col1.map({k: (v, -ord(k)) for k,v in df.col1.value_counts().to_dict().items()}), ascending=False)
```

Here the result:

```sh
   col1  col2 col3
0     A     1   as
1     A     2   sd
5     A     1   hj
8     A     1   re
2     B     3   df
6     B     3   jk
7     B     4   kt
4     D     6   gh
10    D     6   qw
11    D     7   aa
3     C     5   fg
9     C     5   we
```